# User restrictions integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to narrow input of a integer to a certain length like "7" (per example) from a user `raw_input`:

```
def number():
number=int(input("Number:"))
print(number)

number=1234567
```

It has to have an while condition where it says `if len(number) < 7 or len(number) > 7`:

```
print("Error")
phone=int(input("Number:"))`
```

Thank you & Merry Xmas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting Python input strings to certain characters and lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761778/limiting-python-input-strings-to-certain-characters-and-lengths)

Comment: @AbhishekSingh this is an individual and special case where I need it to be a raw_input and a integer only.

Comment: @Phyti, raw_input  is python2, your quaetion is tagged python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry I meant input

Comment: @PadraicCunningham your code returns the following error: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: @Phyti, not unless you are using python2 or not using my code exactly as posted

Comment: @PadraicCunningham solved the error but is allowing to put more than 7 and less I just wanted 7 is there a way to simplify this with if statements and else, inside the While?

Comment: @Phyti, it is not letting you put more than 7, if you want exactly 7 I have alsoexplained how to do that in my answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I done it and just saw that now on Comments. Thank you and Merry Xmas

Comment: @Phyti no worries, same to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the length before you try casting to int:

```
def number():
    while True:
        i = input("Number:") 
        if len(i) > 7:
            print("Number can only contain at most 7 digits!")
            continue
        try:
            return int(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
```

If you want exactly 7 use  `if len(i) != 7` and adjust the error message accordingly. I also used a try/except as because the length is seven does not mean it is a valid string of digits. If you want to allow the minus son you could `if len(i.lstrip("-")) > 7:`

Comment: I have to say if len(number)<7 or len(number)>7: print("Input Invalid") and to print again raw_input(int("Number")).

Comment: You don't use number at all, you check the length if i and only try casting to int if it is an acceptable length, if you want at most a 7 digit number then `if len(i) > 7:` will work as you want as any length > 7 will not be ignored

Comment: just run the code @Phyti .. the `while True` keeps reprompting until correct input is recieved ...

Comment: Ok I will @JoranBeasley