# Limit raw_input length

Tags: python, raw-input

I'm looking for a solution to limit the number of characters a user can type in a raw_input. I have two raw_inputs in a same line, that looks like this:

```
Name: (user input)                           Date of Birth: (user input)
```

If a user types in a name that is bigger than X amount of characters, it will start writing on top of Date of Birth, like this:

```
Name: Mary Jane Smith McDonald Obama Romney Bushh of Birth: (user input)
```

The closest thing I found was this: [Limiting Python input strings to certain characters and lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761778/limiting-python-input-strings-to-certain-characters-and-lengths), but that wouldn't work for me. I don't want it to show a warning; I want it to simply stop accepting more characters and/or go to the next input.

I'm using blessed, which is a library that uses curses to position the second input in the same line as the first.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunatley, raw_input() is not going to work for you. What you'll need to do is manually handle keyboard input and perform the rendering yourself through curses (or blessed).

Comment: @Aldehir I see. And do you have any idea how could I do that using blessed?

Comment: FWIW, enforcing a length limit on a person's  name is probably not a great design strategy.

Comment: @PM2Ring that is true! But I did leave enough space for a pretty big name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getstr()` which is the `raw_input` alternative for `curses`, works with a character constraint:

```
s = stdscr.getstr(0,0, 15) #Input is limited to 15 characters, once the limit is hit, it stops accepting more
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! My only issue is that I'm already using 'blessed' for a lot of things that would be otherwise overly complicated with 'curses', and I can only use one at a time. Do you know if blessed, or any other curses based library for that matter, has that function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a neat thing I just whipped up, might help someone viewing this thread that isn't using curses. Effectively constrains string length for user input during the input.

```
import readchar
import sys

string = ""

while len(string) < 20:
    c = readchar.readchar()
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    string += c

print '\n' + string
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but when I tried to implement that to my code I got the following error: "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings."

Comment: Would probably need to look at your full source code to give you the best answer. It sounds like you're saving the user inputs into a sqlite database with something like `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,1,1,1)', user_input)`. You should force the user_input to be unicode, `unicode(user_input)`.

Comment: That is exactly what I got but I can still send you the code if you want me to. The problem is, I'm using UTF-8 characters, so I can't use unicode. I first tried to simply replace "(string)" with "(name)" which is a raw_input, but that returned no results. Then I tried "name = "Name:" and that's when I got the error.

Comment: Try `user_input.decode('utf-8')`? If not, post a gist or pastie to your code and I'll take a look.

Comment: this is the original code: https://gist.github.com/lovemac15/c5e71e0b8aa428693e5b and this is after I implemented the code you suggested: https://gist.github.com/lovemac15/b24702f5d21f5eb67b02  this is not the application I was referring to in the question, since I haven't built it yet. I'm trying to limit the raw_input "matricula".