# Python Raw_Input in specific range

Tags: python

I need to allow the user to input only numbers from 1111 to 9999 as raw_input in python. How do I create a constraint for this condition?
Thanks

Comment: with a while loop ?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761778/limiting-python-input-strings-to-certain-characters-and-lengths

Comment: Do you know how to check if a number is between two other numbers?

Comment: By "number" do you mean an integer `int` or a real number `float` or something else?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response). You would then use `num = sanitized_input('Type a number from 1111 to 9999:', int, 1111, 9999)`. I now use that function for my own programs.

Answer (score 2):

Get the input then check if the input is valid to your constraint (e.g. via an `if` condition). If it is not valid repeat the input (probably with notifiyng the user what was wrong with the input before) (e.g. with a `while` loop).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the user to input any specific thing using `raw_input()`. You'll have to validate the user input and preferably use a while loop until user enters correctly.

This will work (assuming the user is not stupid to input non-digits).

```
i = int(raw_input('Please, enter a number between 1110 and 10000'))
while not(1110<i<10000):
  i = int(raw_input('Dude, come on, read the instruction'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop until the user inputs a valid number. Check for ValueError to eliminate invalid input.

```
user_input = -1
_continue = True
while _continue:
    try:
        user_input = int(raw_input("Value: "))
        if 1111 <= user_input  <= 9999:
            _continue = False
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
is_input_valid = False
while is_input_valid == False:
    inp = int(raw_input("Input your number: "))
    if inp >= 1111 and inp <= 9999:
        is_input_valid = True
    else:
        print "Please input only numbers from 1111 to 9999"

print "Thanks, your input is valid"
```