# How do I add a specific letter to a variable and then make it a string

Tags: python, string, variables, input, addition

I am trying to make a hangman game and I am not fully sure on how to add a specific letter to a variable.
For example, adding a letter that someone chose through the pythons' input prompt to a variable. Here is the code I am working on:

```
import random
import time

word_list = ['that', 'poop', 'situation', 'coding', 'python', 'turtle', 'random', 'passive', 'neutral', 'factor', 'time']
word_chosen = random.choice(word_list)

your_name = input("What is your name?")
time.sleep(1)
print("Hello " + your_name + ", lets play some hangman!, The amount of letters in the word is below!")
guesses = 7

time.sleep(1)
hidden_word = ""
for i in word_chosen:
  hidden_word += "-"
while True:
  n = 1
  time.sleep(1) 
  print("Your word is: " + hidden_word)
  print("___________")
  print("|")
  print("|")
  print("|")
  print("|")
  print("|")
  print("|")
  print("|")
 


  characters = (word_chosen)
  time.sleep(1)
  letters_correct = ""
  characters_guessed = input("Type in the letters you think are in this word!")
  for i in characters:
    hidden_word == characters_guessed
    
  if characters_guessed == characters:
    print(hidden_word + characters)
  else:
    int(guesses) - int(n)
    print("Nope, sorry.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code @Noob and made it work. Instead of using strings I have made lists of chosen_word ,characters and characters_guessed .In this code you can even enter more than one word at a time. It automatically fillsup the repitive words and will tell the user if he or she has won or lost the game.

```
import random
import time

word_list = ['that', 'poop', 'situation', 'coding', 'python', 'turtle', 'random', 'passive', 'neutral', 'factor', 'time']
word_chosen = random.choice(word_list)
your_name = input("What is your name?")
time.sleep(1)
print("Hello " + your_name + ", lets play some hangman!, The amount of letters in the word is below!")

guesses = 7

time.sleep(1)
hidden_word = [" - " for i in range(len(word_chosen))]
while guesses>0:
    time.sleep(1) 
    print("Your word is: "+ "".join(hidden_word))
    print("___________")
    for i in range(7):
        print("|")


    characters = list(word_chosen)
    time.sleep(1)
    letters_correct = ""
    characters_guessed = input("Type in the letters you think are in this word!").split()

    for j in characters_guessed:
        if j not in characters:
            guesses-=1
            print(f"Wrong guess, {j} is not in the word")
        else:
            for i in characters:
                if i==j:
                    find_position=0
                    for k in range(characters.count(i)):
                        hidden_word[characters.index(i,find_position)]=j
                        find_position+=characters.index(i,find_position)+1
        
    if " - " not in hidden_word:
        print("Congratulations, you have won the game.The word was {chosen_word}")
        break

    elif guesses==0:
        print("Opps!! out of guesses. You have lost the game.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python strings do not support item assignment, so I would use an array of strings and then use `"".join(hidden_word)` when you want to print the word out. You can loop over the chosen word and then when that letter matches the input letter, fill in that position in your `hidden_word` array.

Here's how I would adapt your code to get the game to run:

```py
import random
import time

word_list = ['that', 'poop', 'situation', 'coding', 'python', 'turtle', 'random', 'passive', 'neutral', 'factor', 'time']
word_chosen = random.choice(word_list)

your_name = input("What is your name?")
time.sleep(1)
print("Hello " + your_name + ", lets play some hangman!, The amount of letters in the word is below!")

guesses = 7
won = False
hidden_word = ["|"]  * len(word_chosen)

while guesses > 0:
  print("Your word is: " + "".join(hidden_word))
  print("___________")
  for _ in range(5):
      print("|")

  guessed = input("Type in the letters you think are in this word!")
  for c in guessed:
    for i in range(0, len(word_chosen)):
        if word_chosen[i] == c:
            hidden_word[i] = c

  if "|" not in hidden_word:
      won = True
      break

  guesses -= 1

if won:
    print(f'Word found: {"".join(hidden_word)}')
else:
    print(f'Nope, sorry - word was {word_chosen}')
```

So to answer your original question, I assign the string that is input to `guessed`. I then loop over each letter in `guessed`, and check it against each position in `chosen_word`. If the letter at that position is a match, I change the placeholder `|` to the chosen letter. Once no placeholders are left, the game is won.

If you wanted to limit the user to only inputting one character at a time, I would take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761778/limiting-python-input-strings-to-certain-characters-and-lengths) thread for example on how to adapt `input()` to handle this.